# pre_get_posts hook not targeting search results page query

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to target search result page query with this code:

```
function my_custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'highlight',
            'value' => '0'
        )
    ) );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_custom_search_query');
```

This code is not working.
If post has an ACF field meta value set to true, exclude it.

[image]

Comment: Your `if`'s expression does not seem correct. Try with `if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_search() ) { return; }` ..

Comment: I want to not affect queries in admin but in frontend, as docs says: "Make use of conditional tags to target the right query. For example, its recommended to use the the is_admin() conditional to not change queries in the admin screens."

Comment: I know and that code I gave, it means "if is in wp-admin, or the query is not the main query, or the current page is not a search results page, then do nothing; else, we set the meta query". Have you tried that code?